# How to modify style to a link in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, hyperlink, styles

How can I make the text in the div (the content of the variable name) become a link? In other words:  To change the style to "a" without using jQuery.

```
var newtit=document.createElement('div');
newtit.id=name; // name is a variable
newtit.innerHTML= name; 
document.getElementById("w3c").appendChild(newtit);
```

Comment: Do you want to style the text like a link or do you want it to actually be a link to another page?

Comment: An `a` isn't a style, it's an HTML element.  You can create one in exactly the same way you do with your `div` element.

Comment: I need to link to an element (like href="#top") Thanks a lot Coda17

Comment: Thanks a lot David, could you write me an example because I can't manage to put the `a` inside the `div`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do what you did with a div, but instead of creating a div, create an anchor element. Add the link you want as the href-attribute.

```
var newtit=document.createElement('a');
newtit.href = "http://www.google.com"
newtit.innerHTML= "linkylink"; 
document.getElementById("w3c").appendChild(newtit);
```

Based on your content, first create the div then append the anchor element to it

```
var tab = document.createElement("div");
tab.id = "TabX";
document.getElementById("w3c").appendChild("tab");

var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = "#TabX";
link.innerText = "Tab XX";
document.getElementById("TabX").appendChild("tab");
```

or just write the anchor straight to the inner HTML

```
tab.innerHTML = "<a href='#TabX'>Tab XX</a>"
```

Comment: The problem is that when I make like this, I lose the style of the tab [link](http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/previo/thump_8933083captura-de-pantalla.png)

Comment: The other divs are like this `<div id="tab18"> <a href="#tab18">Tab 18</a> <div>... that 2 should have been enough, but...</div>`